# como generar descuento con condición?

Tags: vue.js

soy nuevo en la programación y estoy tratando de generar un descuento condicionado del subtotal que genera el código que esta mas abajo pero no tengo ni la mas mínima idea de como hacerlo, por favor si alguien me podría orientar en este tema o si tiene algún dato que me sirva se los agradecería mucho.
espero me puedan ayudar y de antemano muchas gracias

aquí el codigo

```
subtotal: (state) => {
      return state.carrito.reduce((a, b) => {
        const equipo = state.equipos.productos.find((p) => p.id == b.id);
        const totalByEquipo = b.cant * equipo.precio_promo;
        return a + totalByEquipo;
      }, 0);
    },
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es realmente el problema? Suena a que tu pregunta no es de programación, sino de lógica.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias poner tus variables de forma mas clara ya que no explicas el contexto de la compra. segun el nombre de la funcion solo estas devolviendo el subtotal.
En nivel logico Subtotal = cantidad * precio.

Luego a eso se le restas el descuento para obtener el total.
Lo puedes obtener en otra funcion, o aprovechar la misma aunque eso haria que el nombre de la funcion ya no tenga logica.

Yo lo haria de la siguiente forma:

```
montoFactura: (state) => {
           const montos={subtotal:0,total:0}
           state.carrito.forEach(item=>{
           const equipo = state.equipos.productos.find((p) => p.id == b.id);
             const valorBruto=item.cantidad*equipo.precio;
             montos.subtotal+=valorBruto;
             montos.total+=
                valorBruto
               //Se le resta el valor del descuento Solo si este es mayor a 0
               //Asumiendo que el descuento esta en forma porcentual ejemplo 5
           -(equipo.descuento>0?valorBruto*(equipo.descuento/100):0)
          });
         return montos;
    },
```

Suponiendo que solo hay un item que vale 100 $ y tiene 3% de descuento, esta funcion devolveria

{subtotal: 100, total:97}

Comment: buenas noches, primero que todo una disculpa por no revisar antes ya que no he tenido tiempo de revisar y gracias por tu comentario padaleiana y si tienes razon creo que es de las 2 de logica y programacion a continuacion tratrare de explicar el caso y aquiles gracias a ti tambien por responder. el codigo es un getter que se solo me da un subtotal de la compra de equipos telefonicos  lo que yo queria ver es como usar esa respuesta que me da este getter y sacar un porcentaje de descuento si la compra del equipo es inferior a $100 o un diferente descuento si la compra es mayor a $100

Comment: y como total la resta del subtotal y el descuento aparte. espero haberme explicado bien ojala me puedan ayudar otra ves

Comment: Ummm ya entiendo, bueno eso lo puedes hacer fuera de esta funcion, una vez recibas el valor del getter, puedes evaluar que tan alto es el monto y aplicarle un descuento. pero ya seria fuera de esta funcion.